# How to implement Facebook Login and Signup in Java REST api

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, oauth, openid

I have been able to get the access code from the redirect url after which I have to use it request for the access token to the Facebook. The approach used was through oAuth2.0.
I am primarily building and Android app which have fb login feature. I have implemented the android part where user have to use Fb app and Fb will re-direct to the callback url. The server side is based on Dropwizard Maven Project.
I have read enough of the OpenID, OpenID with oAuth, restfb but still not able to know which of the three to use and how.
In oAuth2.0 , I am not able to configure how to get the access token and call the graph api within the resource file. Can I call a url of the fb graph api within the resource file? Is this possible to call an api from within an api or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an endpoint in your rest services so you store the AccessToken.

Then when you need something from the resource server just create FacebookTemplate (userToken) and there you have all the userOperation, feedOperations etc.. for the specific user holding that token.

That is a good approach for an app, because in that way you will be able to get facebook resources by server to server calls - then store the info needed in the database. then in your front end- mobile part just query your database and the imported facebook info will be there.